# Page header - full width

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this page in my application:

http://actibities-uniongr.rhcloud.com/pages/view-demo

If you shorten your browser's window to less than 1000px and scroll horizontally you'll see that the header doesn't span (doesn't fill the full width of the screen). It happens only to this page that has an iframe (youtube embed).

Any idea?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by "header doesn't span"?

Comment: @Rich Sorry for not being understood, I mean that it doesn't fill the screen.

Comment: I see. Would you post a screenshot? It is filling the screen when I resize it below 1000px. What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using safari and firefox. With which browser did you try so I can insert a help text in this page to be viewed with your browser :P ? Thank you.

Comment: There is noting wrong with the header. The basic problem is that the YouTube video has a fixed width of 650px in the iframe. Once you get down to a certain page width, it breaks out of the container causing a scrollbar. You'll have to find a way of making the video scale with the page.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is caused due to one of the property applied to YouTube container.

Try this out:

remove property `-moz-box-sizing:border-box` from class `.row-fluid [class*="span"]`.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the header.

The basic problem is that the YouTube video has a fixed width of 650px in the iframe. Once you get down to a certain page width, it breaks out of the container causing a scrollbar. You'll have to find a way of making the video scale with the page.

See Here: [**SO Link**](http://bit.ly/12bfUq0)